# Adding up numbers in custom fields on a monthly basis

Tags: php, wordpress, date, numbers, addition

Every time i help out a client with a request i make a new post on my wordpress-site. I write a little text about what the problem was, assign the post to the clients own specific category and i fill inn the number of minutes it took me to accomplish the request. The number of minutes i insert in a custom field (using the advanced custom field plugin).

Then, i bill my client on a monthly basis according to how long time i have spent solving request.

I have accomplished to query out the number of minutes for each request/post and add up the total number of minutes. (update) I used this code which i just found on some forum

```
<?php
// Cat ID please
$catid = 20;
// Meta key name please
$meta_key = 'supporttimer';

$allmiles = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT sum(meta.meta_value)
FROM $wpdb->postmeta as meta
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->posts as posts ON posts.ID = meta.post_id
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships as rel ON rel.object_id = posts.ID
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy as tax ON tax.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms as terms ON terms.term_id = tax.term_id
WHERE meta_key = %s
AND terms.term_id = %d", $meta_key, $catid));
echo '<span class="totalt_supporttimer">Totalt antall supporttimer '.$allmiles . '</span>';
?>
```

*But here comes my problem:*

**I would like the query to check out which month the post was published in, and add up totals on a monthly basis. So lets say i helped a client like this:**

JANUARY

1. request took me 60 minutes
2. request took me 30 minutes

FEBRUARY

1. request took me 45 minutes
2. request took me 15 minutes

Then i would like to query out two seperate boxes saying
You spent 90 minutes on requests in january
You spent 60 minutes on requests in february

Anyone able to solve this problem for me?

Anders

Comment: Do you log these in a db?

Comment: i don't really do anything. I enter the number of minutes an publish. As for the code i have that adds up the total number of minutes (ignoring months), look at my original post which i have updated with the code.

Answer (score 1):

customfields values are stored into the postmeta (include the prefix) table which hold these keys

meta_id     post_id     meta_key    meta_value

so this means you need to combine your query with the details of the post as in the postmeta no details of the date are stored.